# ListPicker not working with MVVM Light

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, mvvm-light, listpicker

I am building a simple windown phone 7 Page. I'm doing MVVM (using MVVM light) and binding a `List<Category>` type property to `ListPicker`. This property is defined in a view model named `AddExpenseViewModel` like below

```
public class AddExpenseViewModel:ViewModelBase 
{
    public List<Category> Categories
    {
        get { return categories; }
        set
        {
            categories = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Categories");
        }
    }
}
```

`Category` class is defined as

```
public class Category
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In my XAML I first define a resource as

`<UserControl.Resources>
    <bs:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocator" />
</UserControl.Resources>`

Then set the `DataContext` of the grid that contains the `ListPicker` as

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" 
              Grid.Row="1" 
              Margin="13,1,11,-1" 
              DataContext="{Binding Path=AddExpenseViewModel, 
                                    Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}">
```

And here is my XAML for `ListPicker`

```
<toolkit:ListPicker 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Height="50" 
            Width="200" 
            Grid.Row="2" 
            Grid.Column="1" 
            DataContext="{Binding AddExpenseViewModel}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Categories, Mode=OneWay}" >
            <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Border Background="LightGreen" Width="*" Height="*">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
</toolkit:ListPicker>`
```

This does not work. The `ListPicker` is always empty. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lot of fire-fighting I got this to work myself. Here is what I changed to get this to work

I introduced a new class as below

```
public class Categories : ObservableCollection<Category>
{
}
```

Then I changed the property Categories on my AddExpenseViewModel as below

```
public Categories Categories
{
    get { return categories; }
    set
    {
        categories = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Categories");
   }
}
private Categories categories;
```

Then I changed the ItemsSource on listpicker as

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Categories}"
```

This has got it working.

Answer (score 1):

Do you see any Xaml binding errors in the output while running your application?

You also shouldn't have to bind the DataContext on the ListPicker if you are doing it on a parent element (your Grid).  This could be your issue, but the binding errors should give some detailed info.

Comment: I am seeing the binding error in the output window but that's not helping much. If I remove the DataContext of ListPicker then I get an exception of type MS.Internal.WrappedException with "0x8000ffff" as message. I'm updating the question with further details.

Comment: Could you post the message you're seeing in the binding window?  It generally explains what property failed and how.

Comment: My problem is fixed. I have updated the question with details

Answer (score 0):

Having the Key of your resource being the same as the type is likely the issue.  You could change the case or rename entirely.

Try:

```
<bs:ViewModelLocator x:Key="locator" />
```

and

```
DataContext="{Binding AddExpenseViewModel, Source={StaticResource locator}}"
```

You also shouldn't need to set the DataContext of the Grid and the ListPicker to the same thing. If you're only using the VML in the ListPicker I wouldn't set it on the grid also.

You should use a `TwoWay` binding with a ListPicker as it needs to track the selected Item

Comment: If I remove the DataContext of ListPicker then I get an exception of type MS.Internal.WrappedException with "0x8000ffff" as message. I'm updating the question with further details.

Comment: I found the reason for this error. It had nothing to with data binding. The border in ItemTemplate had height and width set to "*". After changing this to `Auto`, the exception is gone